# Quiz master software?

Tags: software-recommendation

Are there any software for Ubuntu which quiz masters can use to display questions for quiz events?

If there aren't any, what tools or frameworks provide an easir way to build one. Minimum requirements are: a window with eye-candy look, one or multiple text questions on each page, display of multiple images or a single picture and also ability to include videos or sound. There should be an interface to display scores.

Comment: Do you want the software to just display the questions or do you wan them to be interactive?

Comment: Interactivty would be good. But just displaying the questions would do the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try KWordQuiz.
[image]It's not the best, or necessarily the most appropriate, but it gets the job done.

I would also suggest using KompoZer or a similar program from creating a quiz in HTML, or possibly even OpenOffice.org(LibreOffice) impress/writer. All 3 can create a presentation style quiz, which you could then convert to PDF format (built into OOo) for display.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried gbrainy game ? That has features such as full screen, difficulty level,  puzzles/mental calculation/memory trainers, etc.

Comment: that's not the kind of software he is looking for unfortunately. He wants something for creating new quizzes. *NB* I didn't vote up/down, just letting you know why the voter voted down.

Comment: No problem, i'm a novice who just tried help.